Nexjt.s frontend doesn't have PWA setup but still chrome gives option for PWA magically
I have my nextjs dashboard setup without any configs for PWA but google browser gives option for PWA.
Upon installation, the PWA seems to be magically working as well. I am confused, is this a new google chrome update to automatically do this without any configs from the application?
I have not done anything to setup PWA.
Here is the PWA App in the task Bar


Here is the service worker tab section (empty)


Found the reason. This is an actual new chrome feature.
Developers don't have to setup service workers anymore since PWA is supported for most applications by chrome from now on.
You can install a web app as an app in Google Chrome on your computer or Android device:

Open Chrome and go to the website you want to install.
Select More in the top right corner.
Select Save and share.
Select Install page as app.
Follow the on-screen instructions.


That makes sense as your screenshot confirmed no service workers are registered. Next.js's docs also point to customizations to add it.
Thanks for digging and clarifying this for everyone!

Also, from what I heard from my friend - chrome will also prompt you(like the screenshot above) if chrome notices that you use the app regularly.

That's interesting. I am following the topic and PWA are still not part of the starter templates for Next.js. As far as I can tell the Admin Dashboard template has no PWA implemented as well.
Even in the upcoming version 15, PWA is added as an extra step (an easy one). Most popular ways are:

Next-PWA package - https://ducanh-next-pwa.vercel.app/docs/next-pwa/getting-started
Manually adding a service worker - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-service-worker/README.md

Can you share which template exactly are you using for this and include your Next.js version? Perhaps, it's a custom template that has PWA added on top of the default npx create-next-app@latest cli command.
In any case, can you check the service-workers under application and confirm the source of the service worker (see below)? It might be external one coming from outside your next.js app.

Hope this helps!

I am using just npx create-next-app and version is "14.2.2".
I don't have any service workers for this applications. I should also mention, I keep seeing "Install as PWA" option occasionally on every site that doesn't every support PWA as well. I will take a screenshot next time I get asked this prompt. Could this be a Google Chrome feature (A/B testing even)
See Screenshot
@Kung Func

I have added these to description too, thanks!

Here is the localhost env running website asking if I need a PWA randomly without any PWA setup. I also get this while running internet websites too Link to Screenshot
